Confused as why TurboTax asking for 2022 Tax Liability to calculate 2023 underpayment penalty
System showed that I owe tax penalty and it started asking few questions to see if it can be waived. One of the questions was 2022 Tax Liability, where it is asking me to enter line 4 from form 2210 of 2022 return.
Here is the screenshot:

I am confused as why it is asking only line 4 and not line 7,10 & 13.
I should mention that my 2022 tax return was filed by a local CPA and the packet he shared contains form 2210 and it has non zero amounts for line 4,7,10 & 13.
Here is my form 2210 for 2022 return.

Line 4 is "current year tax". Notice that TT is asking about 2022, last year. So it is asking about the 2022 tax liability. This is to determine whether the "safe harbor" exception applies:

Generally, most taxpayers will avoid this penalty if they either owe less than $1,000 in tax after subtracting their withholding and refundable credits, or if they paid withholding and estimated tax of at least 90% of the tax for the current year or 100% of the tax shown on the return for the prior year, whichever is smaller

The other lines you mentioned are irrelevant to the current year.

https://imgur.com/MFByWuE -- So, I am assume this is not the actual form 2210 but the worksheet to prepare form 2210. Is this right?

I have no idea what this is. You'll have to talk to the person who prepared this for you. Form 2210 has a large "Form 2210" at the top in bold.

https://imgur.com/JSnoiTm -- This is the header of the form that I was referring to in my above comment.

Yes, it says it's a worksheet
